# Displaying database results in a html table using mysql, php, js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a html page with a form containing an option of three select queries. I need to make a table that can receive and display the data, and I need to do this using a javascript file that has already been written. Following these constraints I'm not sure how to format the table for outputs . here is the code:

```
/** Comportements.js ******/
$(document).ready(

function() // Fonction anonyme principale
{
    // Ecouteur d'événement 
    $('form').submit(executerRequete) ;
    console.log("***** Exécution du programme javascipt *****"); 


    /*** Gestionnaire d'événement **/
    function executerRequete(evt)
    {
        // Pour manipuler le formulaire
        let $form = $(this) ;

        // Quel formulaire a été utilisé ?
        let idForm = $form.attr("id") ;
        let BDLocale = idForm=="pourBDetd" ;

        console.log("Bonjour, je suis la fonction javascript qui s'exécute après la validation du formulaire "+ idForm)
        // Empêcher le comportement par défaut lié à cet événement, c'est-à-dire le rechargement de la page
        evt.preventDefault() ;
        // Récupérer le texte de la requete

        // Supprimer l'entête de la table éventuellement présente dans la page
        $('.sortieBD thead').remove() ;

        // Supprimer le corps de table éventuellement présent dans la page
        $('.sortieBD tbody').remove() ;

        // Supprimer le message d'érreur éventuellement présent
        $('.messageErreur').text('') ;


        let texteRequete = $form.find('[name=requeteChoisie]').val() ;
        console.log("\t J'ai récupéré ce texte de requête : "+ texteRequete) ;


        let adresseDesDonnees ;  
        if(BDLocale) 
        {  adresseDesDonnees = "php/soumettreRequete.php" ;
            console.log("\t Nous allons travailler sur la BD locale de l'étudiant") ;
        }
        else
        {  
            adresseDesDonnees = "https://web2noninfo.lpmiaw.univ-lr.fr/ISI/projet/api/soumettreRequete.php" ;
            console.log("\t Nous allons travailler sur la BD d'un enseignant") ;
        }
        console.log("\t J'envoie la requête à l'adresse "+adresseDesDonnees)
         let optionsAjax = 
            {
            "url" : adresseDesDonnees, // où aller chercher les données    
                "dataType" : "json", // Sous quel format les récupérer
                "type" :"POST",
                "data" : {"texteRequete" : texteRequete }
            } ;
        // Appel Ajax
        var promesseRequete = $.ajax(optionsAjax) ;

        // Le résultat d'un appel Ajax est une promesse, qui peut être tenue ou pas

        // En cas de promesse non tenue (échec de l'appel Ajax), exécuter la fonction erreurAjax
        promesseRequete.fail(erreurAjax);

        // En cas de réussite de l'appel Ajax, exécuter la fonction afficherResultat
        promesseRequete.done(afficherResultatsRequete);
    }


     // Fonction dont l'exécution est déclenchée si l'appel Ajax échoue
    function erreurAjax()
    { 
        console.log("Une erreur Ajax s'est produite, je ne peux pas récupérer les données !") ;
        $('.messageErreur').text('Erreur Ajax !')
    }

    function afficherResultatsRequete(enregistrements)
    {
        console.log("L'appel Ajax permettant de récupérer les infos des utilisateurs a fonctionné !") ;
        console.log("Voici la donnée fournie par le prog php : ") ;
        console.log(enregistrements) ;
        // la variable utilisateurs contient un tableau de données
        // Pour chaque élément de ce tableau, exécuter la fonction afficherUnUtilisateur
        if (false) // Détecter une réponse erronée
        {    erreurAjax()
        }
        else
        {
            let $table=$('.sortieBD table') ;
            // Créer le corps de la table
            var $tbody = $('<tbody>') ;
            var $thead = $('<thead>') ;

            // Créer l'entête du tableau 
            let nomDesChamps = Object.keys(enregistrements[0]) ;
            let $tr=$('<tr>');
            nomDesChamps.forEach(
                function(unChamp)
                {
                    let $th=$('<th>').text(unChamp) ;
                    $tr.append($th) ;
                }
            );// fin forEach
            $thead.append($tr) ;
            $table.append($thead) ;

            // Pour chaque élément du tableau enregistrements, l'afficher
            $(enregistrements).each(
                function()
                {
                    let $ligne = $('<tr>') ;
                    let enregistrement = this ;
                    nomDesChamps.forEach(
                        function(unChamp)
                        {
                            let $td = $('<td>').text(enregistrement[unChamp]) ;
                            $ligne.append($td) ;
                        }
                    );// fin forEach
                    $tbody.append($ligne) ;
                }
            ) ;
            $table.append($tbody) ;
        }


    } // fin de afficherResultatsRequete




} // Fin de la fonction anonyme principale


  ); // Fin $(document).ready
```

I will have three select queries for a single table in the database with four columns; id, plate, price, and type.

Comment: That's surely an question you will find answer with some searching.

Comment: not with these constraints

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me (though not a JS expert by any means) that your PHP code needs to JSON-encode the array of results from your query to return it to the calling JS. The JS function displays each of the array keys as table headers, then loops through all the array elements and appends them as table rows. Although to my eye, it also looks as if it opens the various table-related HTML tags but never closes them, maybe something else does that automatically.

What happens when you try it, with some `console.log` added?

Comment: THat's not the issue, the code will have been handled correctly in the php file, I just need to know how to format the table. Will this <table class="sortieBD">
     </table> be enough to recieve the data?